# Scale a UIScrollView (not only its content)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I have `UIScrollview` with a couple of `UIViews` init.

If I scale it doesn't really scale my `scrollview` but it scales the content in my `scrollview` in a very weird way,

```
 _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-60.0f)];
 [self addSubview:_scrollView];
 [_scrollView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(_scrollView.layer.affineTransform, .5, .5)];
```

Is it possibly to scale the `scrollview` in its whole and not only the content.
I want to zoom it like my `UIScrollView` as an image and not a control.

Comment: You want zooming effect??

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve

Comment: Cant you use UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Yes thats not the problem the problem is i want to zoom it in its whole and not only the content

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withScrollView:(UIScrollView *)yourScrollView {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    zoomRect.size.height = [yourScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [yourScrollView frame].size.width / scale;


    zoomRect.origin.x = (yourScrollView.theScrollView.x - zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = (yourScrollView.center.y - zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;

    }

    ...

    [yourScrollView setFrame:[self zoomRectForScale:5 withScrollView:yourScrollView]];
```

Comment: This will not scale my contents inside, it needs to be both :)

Comment: autoresizesSubviews = YES ?

Comment: This in combination with standard zoom functionality should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it if you add a UIScrollView inside UIScrollView
and use the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return innerScroll;
}
```

and only connect the mainScroll to the delegate
then add your subviews inside the innerScroll